# Loading redshift table from multiple s3 folder using manifest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, manifest

I am using copy command to load a Redshift table from s3 using manifest.

The requirement is to load multiple files ( across various folders ) for e.g

```
Path1 : s3://bucket_name/folder_name/folder_1/folder/part*.parquet
Path2 : s3://bucket_name/folder_name/folder_2/folder/part*.parquet
Path3 : s3://bucket_name/folder_name/folder_3/folder/part*.parquet
```

each path will have ~1000 files

How do I create a manifest to load this ?

I created a manifest as follows :

```json
{
    "fileLocations": [ 
{"url":"s3://bucket_name/folder_name/folder_1/folder/part*.parquet", "mandatory":false},

 {"url":"s3://bucket_name/folder_name/folder_3/folder/part*.parquet", "mandatory":false},

 {"url":"s3://bucket_name/folder_name/folder_2/folder/part*.parquet", "mandatory":false},

 ]
}
```

but I am getting an error:

> Manifest does not contain a list of files.

Comment: Do you have any documentation that suggests that wildcards are permitted in the manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Using a manifest to specify data files - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html):

> The following example shows the JSON to load files from different buckets and with file names that begin with date stamps:

```json
{
  "entries": [
    {"url":"s3://mybucket-alpha/2013-10-04-custdata", "mandatory":true},
    {"url":"s3://mybucket-alpha/2013-10-05-custdata", "mandatory":true},
    {"url":"s3://mybucket-beta/2013-10-04-custdata", "mandatory":true},
    {"url":"s3://mybucket-beta/2013-10-05-custdata", "mandatory":true}
  ]
}
```

The problem is probably your use of `fileLocations` vs `entries`.

I also **suspect that the use of wildcards is not permitted**.